# update multiple values into table field

Tags: php, loops, foreach, sql-update

I'm trying to update multiple values into table field using foreach. This **$v = implode(",",$v);** returns **3,4,5,**. But, In db table it only updates last value **5,**. How do I update all values?

```
            foreach($var1[57] as $v) {
                $v = implode(",",$v); // THIS RETURNS 3,4,5,
                $sql = "UPDATE ".GAME_REQUIREMENTS_DB." SET operating_system_os = '".$v."' WHERE post_id = '".$id."' ";
            }

            var_dump($sql);
            $update_query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $update_query->execute();
```

Comment: Probably you should use IN: `$sql = "UPDATE ".GAME_REQUIREMENTS_DB." SET operating_system_os IN ('".$v."') WHERE post_id = '".$id."' ";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it works

```
                $sql = "UPDATE ".GAME_REQUIREMENTS_DB." SET operating_system_os = '";
                foreach($var1[57] as $v) {
                    $sql .= "".$v."| ";
                }
                $sql .= "' WHERE post_id = '".$id."'";
```